# Overflow in a flex-child element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i can't make a long text 'go down' a line.

i have a flex object :

```
.gameplay{
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 60%;
     flex: 0 0 60%;
    -webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;
     flex-flow:row wrap;
     justify-content: space-around;
     align-items: flex-start;
     height:100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
}
```

inside of the flex object , i have a regular div :

```
#allcards {     
      display:block;
      width: 300px;
      height: 30px;
      color: aqua;
      overflow: visible;
      font-size: 20px;
}
```

the div , won't respect the width element , when i put in a long text , the text will overflow in the same line! it wont go down a line.

any solutions please ?

HTML code :

```
<div class="gameplay">
<div id = "allcards">  some long text..that doesnt respect the width property , it just keeps going in the same line , out of the divs throughout whole page </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your html code please?

Comment: add " to the end of "allcards == "allcards". If i understood right, you want loooooooong to be on top and text to be below (second line)??